# bash syntax error near token `fi'

Tags: command-line, bash

When I open the terminal, I get the following 2 lines

```
bash: /home/kyle/.bashrc: line 119: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

bash: /home/kyle/.bashrc: line 119: `fi'
```

I don't know why that started or if it's normal. What causes the syntax error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Or, can you point me in the right direction for documentation? I'm inexperienced and am looking to learn.

Comment: Please [edit] you question to include the relevant lines of the `~/.bashrc` file (for example, using command `cat -ne ~/.bashrc | sed '110,$!d'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a new terminal window the system starts a new instance of your shell. In your case that is `bash` (Bourne Again SHell)

When `bash` starts it reads a bunch of startup scripts which configure various things like your prompt, colors, etc. One of these scripts is file `.bashrc` in you home directory. For more info on that check [What is a .bashrc file and what does it do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do)

More info on `bash` scripting: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting

In your case that file has been edited and now is not a valid `bash` script. Therefore the error message `line 119: syntax error near unexpected token...`

That is why steeldriver asked you to post the content of that file so we could see what is wrong with it.

That file is optional. If you want you could rename it to something else - `.bashrc.old` for example and open a new window. The error messages will be gone but prompts, colous and other shell customisations will be gone too.