# Bash no such file or directory every time I open the Ubuntu terminal

Tags: bashrc, ros

I am new to Ubuntu. I was trying to add:

```
echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then I reloaded .bashrc with:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now I am stuck with this. Every time I start terminal I get this first:

[image: Screenshot #1]

```
bash: /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/ros/Home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

Edit:
After `cat ~/.bashrc` I get the following (last lines of file):

```
else 
    if [ -f "/home/ros/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then 
        ."/home/ros/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else 
        export PATH="/home/ros/anaconda3/bin:$PATH" 
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup 
# <<< conda initialize <<<

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash 
source /catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/Home/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

And `ls ~/catkin_ws/devel` gives:

```
cmake.lock  local_setup.bash  setup.bash      setup.zsh
env.sh      local_setup.sh    setup.sh        share
lib         local_setup.zsh   _setup_util.py
```

[image]

Comment: Does that file exist? If don't know what `.bashrc` file does, read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: yes this file exists, when I was using it with the above code it showed error like the file doesn't exist but when I changed it from ".bashrc" to ".bash" it woked but the message was kept on coming.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat ~/.bashrc` so we can see the contents of your .bashrc file. And also add output of `ls ~/catkin_ws/devel`.

Comment: I have just added that to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking at the end of your `.bashrc`, can you see the problem?

It looks like you tried to do the command `echo "source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` several times, and some of them included errors.

What you need to do is to edit your `~/.bashrc` file, for instance using nano:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Now, remove all the lines you don't need at the end (after `# <<< conda initialize <<<`). I assume you also need the file `/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`, so leave the following lines:

```
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash 
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```