# Whenever I open terminal , My terminal is running some process but why?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, zsh

I am new to ubuntu . I have never used any linux based OS before .I am using zsh shell . I was setting up a development of a open source project on my machine for open source contribution . I followed up their setting up development guide . After setting up all whenever I open my terminal,after every fresh boot up, I see that some process is running , I have to press Ctrl + C to stop that process and do my work (Please see screenshot below) . My machine boot up time is also increased . I have checked that no docker container is running .

I had made some changes for development in .zshrc file . May be I had wrote wrong syntax that is  causing  this problem ? I don't know that much about on how to edit .zshrc file . If you know please let know .

I searched regarding this problem of my terminal on internet but I didn't find any solution for it .

If anyone knows what I have done wrong , please let me know . It will be great help as I will get to know new things.

[Some process is running but don't know which one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObXqf.png)

[I pressed Ctrl+C to stop the process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJUa1.png)

[I added this line in .zshrc file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ZMG.png)

Thanking You,

Yours Truly

Rishabh Raghwendra

Comment: So... you are sourcing `~/.zshrc` *from `~/.zshrc`*? If so, that's going to create an infinite loop.

Comment: @steeldriver , thanks buddy .. Now the problem is solved . I don't know that much about .zshrc file , may you tell me an best resource to learn about .zshrc file , because it's seems interesting too learn

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do (`.bashrc`, but the logic is the same)