# cd 'no such file or directory'

Tags: directory, cd

I am trying to install cryoSPARC in my computer. At the "<install_path>" stage of the guide I follow (see image below) I entered the command:

```
cd /home/cryosparcuser/cryosparc
```

but it returned:

```
-bash: cd: /home/cryosparcuser/cryosparcuser/cryosparc: No such file or directory.
```

I don't quite know where the problem is.

Here is the relevant part of the guide I follow:

[image: 'install_path' stage]

Comment: That `cd` command is probably just an example. The files are probably in your own home directory on some sub-directory thereof.

Comment: to add: please do not install in /home/ directly (you run into problems if later in time you create a user with the same name) You are expected to change "cryosparuser" to the user you used to install this software. cryosparcuser does not exist in /home. That's why you get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That step in the installation guide is telling you to change directory (`cd`) to the directory where you want to install cryoSPARC. The subsequent steps in the guide have you download and extract the files for cryoSPARC, which will occur in your present directory when you run them. So, if you aren't positive on where this should be, you can create a directory for this in your home directory (`~`):

1. Change directory to your home directory:

   ```
   cd ~
   ```
2. Create `cryosparc` directory:

   ```
   mkdir cryosparc
   ```
3. Change directory to the new install location:

   ```
   cd cryosparc
   ```

From here you can proceed with the installation per the guide (I am assuming you are using this page: https://guide.cryosparc.com/setup-configuration-and-management/how-to-download-install-and-configure/downloading-and-installing-cryosparc)

Comment: As the OP seems to be new to the Linux command line, it's worth noting that `~` is a "short way" to write `/home/username` (usually referred to as "home"), where `username` is the name of the user you are logged in with. Using as an example the OP's username here as `username`, `~` would be equivalent to `/home/Falio`.

Comment: Thank you! This seems working and I now have my application installed. At the end, it asked me  'Add bin directory to your ~/.bashrc ?', do you know what does it mean?

Comment: The `~/.bashrc` file is a configuration file that is executed every time you open a new terminal. You can read more about it in this question: [What is a .bashrc file and what does it do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540683/what-is-a-bashrc-file-and-what-does-it-do)

Comment: The `bin` directory you are asking about must contain the cryoSPARC binaries (I suspect that this is the case, but I'm not 100% sure, since I haven't installed the program), and is probably created during installation somewhere inside the `~/cryosparc` directory. It should not be confused with the `/bin` directory that is located at the root (`/`) of the filesystem. Adding the cryoSPARC `bin` directory path in `~/.bashrc` lets you use its binaries (or commands if you prefer) just by using their names, without having to type the whole path to them.